# Gradle dependent task doesn't pass command line options to parent task

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm writing a custom Gradle task that accepts an option from the command line. That part works as expected. What's causing me issues is that calling a dependent task, the command line option is rejected because it's not relevant to the dependent task. Here's a sample that demonstrates the issue:

```
class CustomTask extends DefaultTask {
    @Option(option = "stuff", description = "Custom task stuff")
    String stuff

    @TaskAction
    void action() {
        if (this.stuff?.trim()) {
            println this.stuff
        }
        else {
            throw new InvalidUserDataException("No stuff!")
        }
    }
}

task custom(type: CustomTask)

task depends(dependsOn: 'custom')
```

Here are the paths:

1. `gradle custom` correctly throws an exception
2. `gradle custom --stuff=mystuff` emits `mystuff` when the task runs.
3. `gradle depends` correctly throws the same exception
4. `gradle depends --stuff=mystuff` fails with `Unknown command-line option '--stuff'`

How do I make the command line option `--stuff` pass through to the `custom` task when calling the `depends` task?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's one of the documented limitations of options https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#limitations

Comment: You're correct! That's utterly moronic though. If you'd post that as the answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: "utterly moronic" is a little harsh, but I agree it could be better. You could use build properties instead, and pass them in with `-Pstuff=something`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's one of the documented limitations of options https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#limitations

You could use build properties instead, and pass them in with `-Pstuff=something`

Comment: That's exactly what I switched to after your original comment. Thanks again!