# Gradle set property in custom task

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have a gradle task which runs some code checks, which is usually executed during build.
Since this tasks takes a long time, I implemented a flag so that it is not run during normal build, but needs to be enabled via a property:

```
tasks.withType(MyTaskType) {
    //config switch "-Pcheck=true"
    enabled = project.getProperties().getOrDefault('check', false).equals('true')
}
```

Now I can start it in the terminal via: `./gradlew build -Pcheck=true`

Now I also want to have a task "buildWithCheck", which sets this property and then executes the build task.

How can I do this? What I tried:

```
task buildWithCheck {
  doFirst{
    project.getProperties().put('check','true')
  }
  dependsOn tasks['build']
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle dependent task doesn't pass command line options to parent task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171801/gradle-dependent-task-doesnt-pass-command-line-options-to-parent-task)

Comment: Apparently, this is not possible at the moment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171801/gradle-dependent-task-doesnt-pass-command-line-options-to-parent-task

Comment: @JoschJava That question specifically says `-Pparameters` are a viable solution to a problem with `--full-command-line-args` so isn't the same thing. IT doesn't however address _changing_ them internally to `build.gradle`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Task `enabled` is evaluated very early in the DAG creation so cannot be overridden by other tasks. What you want is the `onlyIf` condition. Below code allows checks to be run either way:

```
gradle test -Pcheck=true
gradle testSlowly
```

**build.gradle**:

```
ext {
    check = project.properties['check'] ?: "false"
}

task test {
    onlyIf { project.ext.check == "true" }
    doLast {
        println "TEST"
    }
}

task testSlowly {
    doFirst{ project.ext.check = "true" }
    finalizedBy 'test'
}
```

**build.gradle.kts** (for kicks, I tried doing this in Kotlin too)

```
var check: String by extra { properties.getOrDefault("check", "false") as String }

tasks {
    val test by registering {
        onlyIf { check == "true" }
        doLast {
            println("TEST")
        }
    }
    register("testSlowly") {
        doFirst { check = "true" }
        finalizedBy(test)
    }
}
```